# Getting Excel row data to mysql column in php

Tags: php, mysqli, phpexcel, excel-match

I know how I can get data from excel to mysql using php. Please have look at the excel chart below:

[image: Excel file]

I want to input data in below mysql table. 
From the excel file column D,E,F,G data will insert as row in mysql table & column A,B,C & H will input as column but will follow the no of row as A,B,C & D

[image: MYSQL TABLE WITH DATA]

I feel what I'm asking is a bit complicated. But please try to give some idea or advise on how to do that. I can't change the excel file, because there are many files to proceed this way.

Comment: what is the status of the question? If one solved it, it should be marked as solved by accepting an answer. If you don't know how, please ask. It's just a matter of ticking the gray checkmark next to an answer till it turns green.

Comment: Where's the code for all this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically one row from Excel will insert/update 4 rows in MySQL.
May use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io) for an easy iteration of Excel file.

The logic in in `pseudo-php-code` will be something like:

For *inserts* only:

```
// Statement prepare
$DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$base., $user, $pass);
$ST = $DB->prepare('insert into table(field1, fiel2, ..) values (:field1, :field2, ..)');

// Excel iteration
while ($Row = $Excel->NextRow()) {
  $ST->execute(['field1' => $Row['A'], .. 'field2' => $Row['D']]);
  $ST->execute(['field1' => $Row['A'], .. 'field2' => $Row['E']]);
  $ST->execute(['field1' => $Row['A'], .. 'field2' => $Row['F']]);
  $ST->execute(['field1' => $Row['A'], .. 'field2' => $Row['G']]);
}
```

For *synchronization*:

```
// Statement prepare
$DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$base., $user, $pass);
// Update statement
$ST = $DB->prepare('update table set field2 = :field2 where field1 = :field2 and ..)');

// Excel iteration
while ($Row = $Excel->NextRow()) {
  $ST->execute(['field1' => $Row['A'], .. 'field2' => $Row['D']]);
  $ST->execute(['field1' => $Row['A'], .. 'field2' => $Row['E']]);
  $ST->execute(['field1' => $Row['A'], .. 'field2' => $Row['F']]);
  $ST->execute(['field1' => $Row['A'], .. 'field2' => $Row['G']]);
}
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. Could you please give me complete code/script, a bit hard for me to understand, as a beginner.

Comment: Complete working script just for copy/paste? I like charity, but rarely code for it :) i gave you the approach, start thinking. StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Here below the code,its fine now.

```
$fft1=888;
$fft2=777;
$fft3="";
$fft4=999;

$fft5=100;
$ctnqty=10;
$friendslist = "$fft1,$fft2,$fft3,$fft4";
$id = $fft5;
$friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);
  $frienduserarray = array();

for ($n = 0; $n < count($friendarray); $n++) {
  $friendidpush = "('".$id."','".$friendarray[$n]."','".$ctnqty."'),";
  array_push($frienduserarray, $friendidpush);
 }
 $query = "INSERT INTO freddyhipment (style, orderno,ctnqty) VALUES ";
 $friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);

 foreach ($friendarray as $order) {
$query .= "('" . $id . "','" . $order . "','" . $ctnqty . "'),";
}

$query = substr($query, 0, -1); // remove trailing comma
```